# Solution to least squares problem

Tags: least-squares, svd

I was reading through a least squares text book and I am curious to why this is true.
Let A ∈ R m×n have rank(A) = r, which has full rank. Show that $||A^{+}||_{2}$ = $1/σ_{r}$. $σ_{r}$ is the smallest singular value of A.

Comment: could you clarify what $A^+$ means? I never have seen this notation before. Also $\|\cdot \|_2$ means Euclidean norm?

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: what is the norm of a diagonal matrix? And do you mean that $\sigma_r$ is the smallest singular value?

Comment: $A^{+}$ is the pseudo inverse

Comment: Yes I have tried

Comment: @gohan and where did you get stuck?

Comment: After doing svd on $A^{+}$ for example,  $||A^{+}||_{2} = ||V^{T} D^{-1} U||_{2}$, i am not sure what to do with orthogonal matrices.

Comment: @gohan have you an idea what is the norm of a diagonal matrix with diagonal say $(1,2)$?